# Having problems logging outside of current method

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason I get a zip code when I log it inside the brackets, but I get a (null) when I attempt to log outside of the brackets. I also declared "zip" inside of my header file. I'm sure that this is a no brainer. A little help?

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray     *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            self.zip = placemark.postalCode;
            **NSLog(@"%@", _zip);**
        }
        }];
    **NSLog(@"%@",self.zip);**
```

PROBLEM SOLVED
EDIT:

Okay after I was able to pass the block into my next method thanks to SIMON:

```
CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray     *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            self.zip = placemark.postalCode;
            **NSLog(@"%@", _zip);**
[self someMethod];
```

I found that I ended up calling the same block over and over. So I was able to use the following code to stop my code from looping and crashing my app, I wrapped my block in the following:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
```

and wrapped my code in this:

```
dispatch_once(&once,^{

});
```

It fixed the problem right up! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the brackets(completionHandler aka callback) will be executed asynchronously.

you may want to split into two different methods.

```
- (void)someMethodYouCall {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray     *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        self.zip = placemark.postalCode;
        **NSLog(@"%@", _zip);**
        [self secondPart];
    }
    }];
}

-(void) secondPart {
    **NSLog(@"%@",self.zip);**
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I take it there's supposed to be some type of selector that's declared somewhere in there? I keep getting an error on that line with "secondPart."

Comment: Okay so I what I did wrong... I understand now; however, now my issue is that the zip code is logging out to the console about 50 times. Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: thats probably because you are calling the same functions multiples times.  the handler should be called only one time, and if multiple place marks is found they will stored inside the NSArray

Comment: So I take it that I need to create a completion handler?

Comment: yes, otherwise you wont be able to get place marks. this kind of programming style is normally used for long running tasks(networking, storage, fetch, etc). and if you execute it on the UI thread, that heavy task won't block the UI thread. instead will run on the background and perform the handler when finished

Answer (score 0):

The completion handler you're using there is asynchronous.

`reverseGocodeLocation:completionHandler:` will call the block you define when it is done with its computation (whenver that is).

Until then, nothing defined there will run.

After the block is posted, the next line of code (the outside `NSLog`) runs as per usual.

It's thus running *before* the completion handler, and before `self.zip` has a value.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. How would I gather this value to use it outside of the block?

Comment: @JulioLopez - you can access it as per normal (with `self.zip`) but only *after* the block has run.  You could achieve this, eg, by calling a delegate method in the block, or by posting a new block to GCD.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this completely new to me do you think you could show me or point me in the direction of a reference to work from? I tried using self.zip and it still came out as "null."

Answer (score 0):

This is because you obtain zip inside a block. It is called a little bit later than code right after it. So if you try to access zip outside these brackets your zip is not initialized yet. What you need is to get acquainted with how blocks work. Here is a good tutorial to start from:[Blocks tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9328/creating-a-diner-app-using-blocks-part-1)

Also take a look at official documentation [Apple official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Comment: Would the __block directive (double underscore) help in this case?

Comment: @Smick no, it woudn't

Answer (score 0):

@Andrey, thanks for info. I wanted to share this I found, may help someone down the track.

http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Ask-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Blocks-in-Objective-C

> There is one wrinkle to using variables external to the block,
>   however: by default they are considered const and cannot be modified
>   (static and global variables are an exception to this). As such the
>   following code produces a compiler error:

```
int matching = 0;
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
if (/* condition */)
    matching++; // Error since matching is const within the block!
}];
```

> By adding the __block storage type modifier we can make this code snippet work:

```
__block int matching = 0;
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
if (/* condition */)
    matching++; // Can modify matching due to __block modifier.
}];
```

Comment: I tried a different approach, but this works too! Check my edit! Thanks!

Comment: Glad mine worked, your method is a nice work around. All comes down to what makes more sense to you. Cheers